# Updating component causes its variable to be undefined (with react-query)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-query

I'm using dnd-beautiful-kit in order to segregate Cards.
Each Card has some informations (presented on the video) and Avatar component.
Avatar can be the image (if avatarSource exist) or an initials of the user.
Also I'm using react query to fetch avatarSource from backend.

Forgive me for not showing the whole, editable code but it is too big to be readable.
The components are in that hierarchy:

```
const Card = (user) => {
  
  return(
     <div>
       {user.name}
       {user.lastName}

       <Avatar userId={user.id}/>
     </div>
  )
}

const Avatar = (userId) => {
  const [avatarSource, setAvatarSource] = useState();

  useQuery({
    queryKey: ["getAvatar", userId],
    queryFn: () => {
      return getAvatar(userId); //here is fetching by axios
    },
    onSuccess: data => {
      setAvatarSource("data:" + data.contentType + ";base64, " + data.fileContent)
    }

    
  return (
   {avatarSource?
    <img style={avatarStyle} id={style.avatar} src={avatarSource} alt="avatar" />
    :
    <div style={avatarStyle} className={style.initials}>
      {user.initials}
    </div>});}
```

After my investigation I realized that the avatarSource becomes undefined after I move card to another column, BUT the user does not. What is more, I hardcoded avatarSrc by passing it straight into <Avatar src={'base64 data....'}/> and then there was no blinking.

In sum, I dont know why:

- react-query does not catch cached value
- avatarSource becomes undefined after update
- how to prevent that blinking

[video](https://streamable.com/imshdy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> react-query does not catch cached value

simply put, because you are not using the returned `data` from react-query, but only relying on local state that you don't need:

```
const { data } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ["getAvatar", userId],
  queryFn: () => {
    return getAvatar(userId); //here is fetching by axios
  }
})

const avatarSource = data && "data:" + data.contentType + ";base64, " + data.fileContent
```

that's pretty much the same as before, just without local state.

when the userId changes, you'll get a new cache entry, which means `data` will be `undefined` and state will be `loading`. To avoid that, you can pass `keepPreviousData: true` to the react-query options.